# Spring Hibernate - Find entities matching fields of another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would assume that Hibernate would have a method of finding entities given another pre-populated entity, querying those who match.
As of my current knowledge; if I want to query an entity with a criteria of multiple fields I would need to add such a method in the `CrudRepository` interface which would look like this: `findByFirstNameAndLastNameAndAddress...` and then every combination i can think of.
 
Is there something along the lines of `queryMatchingInstance(instance)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called query by example.

[It is available in Hibernate directly](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-examples).

And since you tagged the question with `spring-data-jpa`: [Spring Data offers such a feature as well](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).